# Why can I concatenate String and Int in Scala?

Tags: scala, types

I'm trying out some things in Scala, coming from Python. Since Scala is a lot more strict about keeping types consistent, I was surprised to find out that I can do the following concatenation, which would blow up in Python:

```
def adder(one:Any, two:String) = {one+two}

adder("word", "suffix")
```

> res13: String = wordsuffix

But also:

```
val x:Int = 1

adder(x, "suffix")
```

> res12: String = 1suffix

- So it just transforms an `Int` into a `String` w/out telling me. What is this called and what is the logic behind it?
- And what is the benefit of this? I feel it can come back to bite me, e.g. when dealing with user input to a function.

I know this is not very specific and if this is too broad, I'll gladly retract the question.

Comment: If your question is really **_why_** this is so in Scala rather than **_how_** this is done, I suspect that this is done this way because in Java (the main target platform) see [5.4. String Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.4) and also in .Net (historical additional target platform) it works that way. And as to why it is there, I think because of the convenience in some typical usages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an implicit class in `scala.Predef` that operates on objects of any type

```
  implicit final class any2stringadd[A](private val self: A) extends AnyVal {
    def +(other: String): String = String.valueOf(self) + other
  }
```

That implements `Any + String` (as you have defined it in `adder`). As rogue-one mentioned, there is also a method for concatenating `String + Any` [defined in `StringOps`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#+(x$1:Any):String). If you tried to do `Any + Any` it would fail because it's expecting a `String` as the argument.

> So it just transforms an Int into a String w/out telling me

Scala is converting your `Int` into a `String`, but it's not a type conversion because `Int` cannot be coerced into a `String`. You can observe that by trying something like this:

```
def foo(str: String) = ???
foo(5)  // Type mismatch: expected: String, actual: Int
```

That will fail to compile because Scala can't magically coerce an `Int` into a `String`.

> what is the logic behind it?

See [implicit classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/implicit-classes.html)

> And what is the benefit of this? I feel it can come back to bite me, e.g. when dealing with user input to a function.

It's a convenience method that's very specific to `String` and concatenation. This feature is implemented in Java, so I believe it was implemented in Scala to maintain source compatibility. My example above shows that (except in this specific case), user input to a function will respect the types defined on the function.

Comment: also @rogue-one Thanks, that makes sense! Just so I get it right, this works because: this specific instance of `+` has a `String` on one side, where `+` is implemented this way; and:  the `Any` is treated as a `String` no matter what cause that's what the Scala designers found most sensible in this setting?

Comment: Yup that's right. Any other type on the right (e.g. `Any + Any`) would produce an error.

Comment: Actually I think it's less to do with Scala designers thinking it's a good idea, and more to do with being compatible with Java because Java allows you to concatenate objects with `String` magically.

Answer (score 2):

- It's called implicit conversion (or implicit typecasting)
- The purpose - convenience so you don't have to do everything manually. Most high-level languages will do that with the most used generics like strings, ints, bools...

You can check `scala.Predef` to see all the methods used when implicitly converting types, and you can take control of it using `scala.language.implicitConversions`. Read more at [Scala Documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-conversions).

Answer (score 1):

This String concatenation not only works for Int but for any data-type. For instance

```
scala> case class Elephant(value: String)
defined class Elephant

scala> "Hello" + Elephant("elephant")
res2: String = HelloElephant(elephant)
```

This is because of the [method](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#+(x$1:Any):String) `+` defined in StringOps (via Predef) class that accepts argument of type Any. So it is a method that is made available to a String object via implicit conversion that takes an argument of type `Any`. so `"Hello" + Elephant("elephant")` is actually `"Hello".+(Elephant("elephant"))`